# Colorize snippets of text in emacs

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have a few words I would like to highlight, so I want to change the color of those few words only to, say, green.

Is there an easy way to do this in emacs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I've done, using `font-lock-add-keywords`. I wanted to highlight the words `TODO:`, `HACK:`, and `FIXME:` in my code.

```
(defface todo-face
'((t ()))
"Face for highlighting comments like TODO: and HACK:")

(set-face-background 'todo-face cyan-name)

;; Add keywords we want highlighted
(defun add-todo-to-current-mode ()
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil
       '(("\\(TODO\\|HACK\\|FIXME\\):" 1 'todo-face prepend))
       t))
```

Answer (score 3):

The highlight package has `hlt-highlight-regexp-region` and `hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end`, which do exactly what you want.

http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/highlight.el

Answer (score 3):

Use library [***HighLight***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/HighLight). You can use overlays or text properties. You can save the highlighting permanently or let it be temporary. You can highlight in many ways (regexp, mouse-drag,...). Lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `font-lock-add-keywords` to define a new matcher for the string in question, binding that matcher to [some *face* you've defined](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html#Face-Customization) that will display as green. For example:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '("\\<foo\\>" 0 my-green-face))
```

Note that you can specify a particular *mode* where I wrote `nil` above, and the matching forms can take on any of six different styles. See the [documentation for the variable `font-lock-keywords`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification) for the rules and a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them highlighted only temporarily, I find `M-x highlight-regexp` command very helpful, it is especially nice for looking through log files of sorts. For example you made yourself a logging class that outputs some tracing info like `MyClass::function() >` when function is run and `MyClass::function() <` when it exits (can be especially useful sometimes when debugging multithreading issues) then you just ask emacs to highlight some of them green and other red and then you can see how did the execution go.

Comment: This would be the right way to go rather than hacking the font-lock settings especially for quick and dirty temporary highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I use what Dimitri suggested. In particular, I have the following two lines in my .emacs

```
(global-hi-lock-mode t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-h") 'highlight-regexp)
```

Every-time I need to highlight a certain word (or regex) in a buffer, I hit "C-M-h", which then prompts me for the word (or regex) I want to be displayed differently and then for a face to display it in.